# int8 parameter input for imgSessionSaveBufferEx()

Tags: c++

I am trying to execute the imgSessionSaveBufferEx function:

[image]

I would like to save an image into PNG format, what should I input as the parameter for Int8* file_name?

```
imgSessionSaveBufferEx(sessionID, NULL, ______);
```

Comment: Did you try the obvious `"test.png"` ? What went wrong?

Comment: it says argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "Int8 *"

Comment: Add a type cast to `Int8*` like so: `reinterpret_cast<Int8*>("test.png")`.

Comment: it now says 'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'const char [9]' to 'Int8 *' 

i appreciate your help thus far though

Comment: Right. This becomes uglier by the minute: `reinterpret_cast<Int8*>(const_cast<char *>("test.png"))` You should find the person who designed this API and give them a swift bop on the nose.

Comment: yes the code finally compiled! however i cannot find any image file in my directories... i agree that they deserve a bop on the nose HAHA!! thanks so much for your help, i sincerely wish you well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of attempts are below:

```
imgSessionSaveBufferEx(sessionID, NULL, "test.png");

imgSessionSaveBufferEx(sessionID, NULL, reinterpret_cast<Int8*>("test.png"));

// this is the answer, provided by Botje
imgSessionSaveBufferEx(sessionID, NULL, reinterpret_cast<Int8*>(const_cast<char *>("test.png")));
```